# Failed to generate .log file, but output console is there

Tags: java, logging, log4j, serenity-bdd

I have tried to implement logs in the Serenity Cucumber framework and it prints logs in the console but **doesn't generate a .log file**.

This is `logback-test.xml` under `src/test/resources`

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <File name="File" fileName="admin.log">
            <encoder>
                <pattern> %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}
                    [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg ..................%n </pattern>
            </encoder>
        </File>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>admin.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg
                ..................%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="root" level="DEBUG" />
    <logger name="net.serenitybdd" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="net.thucydides" level="INFO" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Added below dependency in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ConsoleAppender` won't write to a file, and will just ignore the `file` configuration element under it. Instead, you should use a `FileAppender`:

```xml
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg..................%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>admin.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg..................%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="root" level="DEBUG" />
    <logger name="net.serenitybdd" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="net.thucydides" level="INFO" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Now it is giving two more errors and nothing prints in console `17:58:53,923 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Could not find an appender named [STDOUT]. Did you define it below instead of above in the configuration file?
17:58:53,924 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - See http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#appender_order for more details.`

Comment: @paul this is another appender

Comment: After updating the `xml` (see description) , it generates the file `admin.log` but it is empty no logs in it.

Comment: @paul you aren't using the FILE appender anywhere

Comment: I don't know how to use, maybe I am using. Can you tell me which file you are looking to see whether is used or not?

Comment: @paul I've edited my answer to contain the full configuration file